# Format the string with escape characters

Tags: c#

I've spent so long on trying to format this in c#, and tried multiple different combinations of it (I won't list them because it will be too many!), but have not been successful. Can someone please give me a hand?

The result I want:

> /LOGGER "\"\server\c$\Packages Log\SSISErrors.txt\""

I'm trying to use a string builder, but that's not making the job easier anyway:

```
string path = String.Format(@"\\{0}\c$\Packages Log\", Environment.MachineName);
StringBuilder buildLogcmd = new StringBuilder();
                    buildLogcmd.Append("/LOGGER ");
                    buildLogcmd.Append(String.Format("\"\\\" \\{0}\\SSISErrors.txt\\ \"\"", path));
```

Current output:

> /LOGGER "\" \\\server\c$\Packages Log\\SSISErrors.txt\

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If you use the at sign you only need to escape quotes by using double-quotes and everything else is a literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        string path = String.Format(@"""\""\{0}\c$\Packages Log\", Environment.MachineName);
        StringBuilder buildLogcmd = new StringBuilder();
        buildLogcmd.Append("/LOGGER ");
        buildLogcmd.Append(String.Format(@"{0}SSISErrors.txt\""""", path));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = String.Format(@"{0}\c$\Packages Log", Environment.MachineName);
StringBuilder buildLogcmd = new StringBuilder();
                    buildLogcmd.Append("/LOGGER ");
                    buildLogcmd.Append(String.Format("\"\\\"\\{0}\\SSISErrors.txt\\\"\"", path));
```